# Docx4j android ae.com.sun.xml.bind error

Tags: android, docx4j

I am using the docx4j android code from this link.

https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml/tree/master/libs

I am getting this error. Anyone has idea , i am not able to figure it out.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.lang.Error: 
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.init(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:906)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:900)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:134)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:86)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:156)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:94)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:451)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:299)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:142)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1164)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:146)
      at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:237)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at ae.javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:186)
      at ae.javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146)
      at ae.javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:348)
      at ae.javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446)
      at ae.javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:409)
      at org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.getPrefixMapper(NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.java:47)
      at org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:67)
      at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:651)
      at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.process(LoadFromZipNG.java:206)
      at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:193)
```

Comment: As it says on the README page, for a modern Android Studio app, using docx4j 3.3.x, please see instead https://github.com/plutext/Docx4j4Android4  You can add "docx to html" to that.

Comment: java.lang.Error: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found

Comment: @JasonPlutext java.lang.Error:javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException:Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found. Also LoadFromZipNG and HtmlExporterNonXSLT is deprecated . I am getting this error when i use docx to html in your updated  project.